# How do I write a float list of lists to file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I need to write a series of matrices out to a plain text file from python.  All my matricies are in float format so the simple 
file.write() and file.writelines()

do not work.  Is there a conversion method I can employ that doesn't have me looping through all the lists (matrix = list of lists in my case) converting the individual values?

I guess I should clarify, that it needn't look like a matrix, just the associated values in an easy to parse list, as I will be reading in later.  All on one line may actually make this easier!

Comment: Can you explain? Why does file.write() not work for you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
m = [[1.1, 2.1, 3.1], [4.1, 5.1, 6.1], [7.1, 8.1, 9.1]]
file.write(str(m))
```

If you want more control over the format of each value:

```
def format(value):
    return "%.3f" % value

formatted = [[format(v) for v in r] for r in m]
file.write(str(formatted))
```

Comment: str(m) produces something different

Comment: Oh, you wrote the other solution. Yes, depending on how the output should be formatted (comma-separated, etc), manual string building might be required.

Comment: I don't think that representation of a matrix is what OP asks for.

Comment: Actually, I like seeing (and upvoted) both your solutions. I admit I also first interpreted the question the way SilentGhost did, but after reading John's solution I have to say that the question leaves the exact output format to inference.

Comment: I guess I should clarify, that it needn't look like a matrix, just the associated values in an easy to parse list, as I will be reading in later.  All on one line may actually make this easier, but thanks to all for your thouhts!

Comment: In the 1st write, it writes just a number but in the 2nd formatted write, the number is printed with ' '. Why?. Can you remove quotation mark in the 2nd formatted write?

Answer (score 11):

the following works for me:

```
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(','.join(str(j) for j in i) + '\n' for i in matrix)
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)?

```
import cPickle as pickle
pckl_file = file("test.pckl", "w")
pickle.dump([1,2,3], pckl_file)
pckl_file.close()
```

Comment: https://intoli.com/blog/dangerous-pickles/

Answer (score 2):

for row in matrix:
    file.write(" ".join(map(str,row))+"\n")

This works for me... and writes the output in matrix format

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle

# write object to file
a = ['hello', 'world']
pickle.dump(a, open('delme.txt', 'wb'))

# read object from file
b = pickle.load(open('delme.txt', 'rb'))
print b        # ['hello', 'world']
```

At this point you can look at the file 'delme.txt' with vi

```
vi delme.txt
  1 (lp0
  2 S'hello'
  3 p1
  4 aS'world'
  5 p2
  6 a.
```