# trying to .write() a float to a datafile.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def filewrite():
    filew = open('company.dat', 'a')
    custid = str(input('Enter Customer ID:'))
    Widg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Widgets Ordered:')))
    Gidg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Gidgets Ordered:')))
    Dood = abs(float(input('Quantity of Doodads Ordered:')))
    filew.write('\n')
    filew.write(custid)
    filew.write(Widg)
    filew.write(Gidg)
    filew.write(Dood)
    filew.close()

def fileread():
    filer = open('company.dat', 'r')
    read = filer.read()
    file.close()
    print(read, end='')

again = True

while again == True:
    print('1 - Add a new Invoice Order')
    print('2 - Display all Invoice Orders')
    print('3 - Quit')

    choice = abs(int(input('Enter 1, 2, or 3:')))

    if choice > 3:
        print('Error, no choice of such available.')
        choice = abs(int(input('Enter 1, 2, or 3:')))

    if choice == 1:
        filewrite()
        print('\n')
```

I want to write floats into a data file but it won't let me (write() argument must be str, not float). Is there a way for me to write a float into a data file or do I have to write it as a str first then convert it to a float

Comment: You should convert it to the str first then write it . Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864883/how-do-i-write-a-float-list-of-lists-to-file-in-python

Comment: You are writing stuff to a text file so the conversion from  a number to a string has to happen somewhere.   If you want the number stored as a binary data in your data file you could use marshaling.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into strings while writing into the file. For better readability, you should append a `\n` to it:

```
filew.write(str(Widg) + '\n')
filew.write(str(Gidg) + '\n')
filew.write(str(Dood) + '\n')
```

Also, you don't have the code written for `Quit` when someone enters `3`. Something like this should work:

```
if choice == 3:
        break
```

I ran your code with above made changes, it works fine. This is the file it produced:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat company.dat 

123445
12134
12310.0
1210.010.010.0
999910.0
10.0
10.0
```

Comment: then convert it back into a float?

Comment: No. While writing in the file, float will be written as a string. But, in the scope of the code it will always be a float value. Just replace your snippet with mine in your code and change nothing else and see what happens. I tested it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are out of options here. write() function accepts only string values so you have to do the necessary conversions before writing and after retrieving the data values. You can use format function to get more control of format in which you want to store values. for example:

```
number = 1
filew.write('{:04d}\n'.format(number))  # 0001 output \n if you want to store on new line
```